# Do any animal have a tendon repair process that is more efficient than in humans?

Tags: tendons, tissue-repair

Tendon injuries are notoriously slow to heal for humans, and quite often do not heal properly due to a variety of reasons. Do any animal have a tendon repair process that is more efficient than in humans? Efficient = faster + higher repair quality. If so, what property(ies) make the  tendon repair process more efficient?

---

I unsuccessfully searched for "tendon repair in animals" on Google and Google Scholar.

Comment: There are vertebrates that can regenerate an entire limb. Possibly there are thousands of animals that are better than humans in tendon repair. Moreover, asking an explanation for all the factors that affect tissue healing is a broad question. You should narrow down your question a bit.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Good point, let's restrict ourselves to the animals that cannot  regenerate an entire limb. Note that while there might be a fair amount of animals in that situation, our knowledge of tendons in animals is quite far from perfect, so the amount of animals known to be in that situation is most likely much more limited, if any. E.g. we only understood quite recently that frogs jump so high thanks to their tendon properties (https://news.brown.edu/articles/2011/11/frogs).